# Minimum information to authenticate a user

Tags: php, sql, security, http, authentication

I have a table who's PK is `INT` type (roughly 4 billion possible unsigned values, however, I will have at most 2 million).  The table also has a `CHAR(32)` column which contains a random value (created using `bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))`), as well as a FK column indicated the userID.

I will send out some emails which will contain links in them, and the links will contain the above table's PK and/or random value, as well as potentially the userID.  The links will also contain an answer (yes, no, etc).  For instance, a link might look like:

```
<a href="ckr.php?rsp=eae8a14011e82cbf385f69b431a17e49&amp;ans=yes">Yes</a>
```

I have a PHP page which will accept a `GET` request (initiated from the above mentioned emails of course) and update the appropriate record in the database with the provided answer if authenticated.

Is solely confirming the 16 byte random value exists in the database enough to authenticate that it came from the user who received the email?  If not, why not and what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I would also use the user id as it is faster.

Your url will become: `ckr.php?userid=1&rsp=eae8a14011e82cbf385f69b431a17e49&ans=yes`

Then, when you check in database, you only check for `userid`. If the user exists, then check for the `rsp` code. If everthing ok, do your job.

Comment: There is no point in adding the user_id. If you set an index on the unique hash column in the database the lookup wouldn't take any longer.

Comment: The table has an index on the random key, so speed isn't an issue.

Comment: @Thomas: I disagree. Searching for a PK will stop at the moment the key is found, searching by an indexed column will not. Not to mention that searching for a number is faster then a 32 char string.

Comment: Understood.  The column will also have a unique index on it, however, it will probably never be duplicated.

Comment: @user1032531: never asume that or your application will have unexpected results.

Comment: @machineaddict  Agree.  My whole point of this post.  If a malicious GET request included a random value in the DB, it would inappropriately update the database.  Yes, adding the userID makes it a little less likely, but that too could be guessed.

Comment: @user1032531 If you invalidate the key after a certain period and only accept one answer per key I don't think this is very likely. You could always use a bigger key if you aren't certain.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, everything send over e-mail is unencrypted an thus **not suitable for authenticating** a user.

Some things you could do to make it a bit more secure:

- Make the key only available for a short timespan. Maybe a 24h window?
- Ask for the users password when receiving the get request.
- Invalidate the key when an answer is received.

Comment: Agree email isn't encrypted, and is concerned an acceptable risk.  Question primarily revolves around using only the single random value.  Note that I am not hashing something to create it so that I may later hash a value and compare it to it.

Comment: Alright, then I think it's ok to use this random key. I would recommend to invalidate this key as soon an answer is received.